# reading CSV data with igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I downloaded the `soc-sign-bitcoinotc` dataset from http://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-sign-bitcoinotc.html

I am trying to use `igraph` to read this data but I am not sure how or where to start.

Each line in the CSV has one rating, sorted by time, with the following format:

```
SOURCE, TARGET, RATING, TIME
```

sample data:

```
6   2   4   1289241912
6   5   2   1289241942
1   15  1   1289243140
```

I tried this:

```
dat = read.csv('soc-sign-bitcoinotc.csv', header=FALSE)
mat = as.matrix(dat)
g = graph.adjacency(mat, mode = c('directed'), weighted = TRUE)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted,  : 
  not a square matrix
```

I assume I am using the wrong method for my data structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `graph.data.frame`. The first 2 columns of `dat` are used for the edge list. The remaining columns are assumed to be edge attributes.

```
g <- graph.data.frame(dat)
```

To get the vertices use `V()`:

```
head(V(g))
+ 6/5881 vertices, named, from 6ace412:
[1] 6  1  4  13 7  2
```

To get the edges use `E()`:

```
head(E(g))
+ 6/35592 edges from 6ace412 (vertex names):
[1] 6 ->2  6 ->5  1 ->15 4 ->3  13->16 13->10
```

Attributes:

```
head(E(g)$rating)
[1] 4 2 1 7 8 8

head(E(g)$time)
[1] 1289241912 1289241942 1289243140 1289245277 1289254254 1289254301
```